# Robustness of installing from deb on RHEL

Tags: centos, debian, redhat, package-management

How robust is the method of converting .deb packages to RPM using alien and then installing on RHEL/CentOS with yum? What are best practices to manage the process?

I have used Debian for several years and am now looking at deploying RHEL-derived for the first time. There are several applications I will want but have not seen in the RPM repositories. It seems that converting .deb packages is the easiest solution.

I don't remember the details, but some time ago, I used alien to convert RPMs and install on Debian and the result was not a clean install. Also, I have heard unspecific remarks that RHEL has some incompatibilities with other distributions.

Comment: What packages are you looking at?

Comment: If I say "package X", then I'll probably just get pointers to some RPM. I'm looking for a solution to the general problem, not the specific case.